# Importing A pdf Image

Tags: graphics, errors, pdf, import

I have an image saved as a pdf file, and I would like to include this image in one of my latex documents. In the preamble of m document, I included \usepackage{pdfpages}; and here is the formatting I used to inser the pdf file:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering 
\includepdf{figure_1.pdf}
\end{figure}
```

And this is the error I receive, 'File `pdfpages.sty' not found." What have I done wrong?

Comment: What is your TeX distro (e.g. TeX Live)?

Comment: That would be TeXstudio.

Comment: Use the package manager of yoour distribution (miktex package manager or tlmgr). Nevertheless, i think `\includegraphics{figure_1}` should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: TeXstudio is the Editor. TexLive or MikTeX? What did you install before texstudio?

Comment: @Mack: TeXstudio is an editor, not a distribution. However, I think you should remove the `;` in case you added it to the package call.

Comment: Oh, I am terribly sorry, I thought TeXstudio was the the distribution. I am using MikTex.

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried doing as you said, but it tried to download a package, and ended up not working.

Comment: Basic Miktex installation? You can check something called »Install missing packages on the fly« somewhere in your preferences. Well, you need a working internet connection.

Comment: @Johannes_B If you are referring to installing the graphicx package, it is already installed, as I have used it several times.

Comment: At the top of the page, press on »stackexchange« and then chat. The problem will be solved there much faster.

Comment: I actually just figured it out: seeing as I wasn't going to use the pdfpages package, but the graphicx package, I removed it from the preamble, and the error messages vanished.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non-issue.